# Semi-Private Comments + page comments -> is it possible?

Tags: custom-field, customization, comments, users

is it possible to do this:

- User need to register and can only see comments written by himself or by an admin. Admins can see all comments
- create a profile page that user can see all their comments related to all posts

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is, it is open source so you can hack it anyway you like as long as you know how to code ;)

There are three ways I see to do this:

1. Find a plugin that does this
2. Write (or modify a existing) plugin to reach this
3. (Bad) For your template edit `comments.php` in order to reach the only see my own comments (or show all comments to admin), for the twentyeleven theme you would also have to edit the `function twentyeleven_comment` that is in `functions.php`

The 3rd option is bad as in not recommended as that makes it harder to update/upgrade in the future.

Obviously 2 and 3 means that you need to mess with the code or hire someone to do it.

Comment: already try but can't find any, plug in or sample code

Comment: A hint (not a sample) look at how wp detects if a comment is held for moderation and what it does then